# absolute position centering with transform having issues

Tags: html, css, position, transform

I have some list items to be centered. I must do it with position absolute as it overlaps another div. I can do it with position and transform properties. But it has a problem when the device width is smaller. I want it to be centered as much long as possible, but it breaks before the device width is enough smaller. I can fix it using **calc**, but what to do when the ul width is unknown?

[codepen](http://codepen.io/salim56668/pen/qarGog)

```css
.parent {
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
}

ul,li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50% , 0);
  clear:both;
  display:block;
}

li {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background: #f44;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `ul` rule like this, where the `left: 0`/`right: 0` will make it full width and `text-align` center the `li`'s

```
ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center
}
```

Sample snippet

```css
.parent {
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
}

ul,li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center
}

li {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background: #f44;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not simply add `text-align: center` to the `ul` tag, without transform or position at all.
If the `li` are inline block, it will be centered and wrap at the `ul` boundaries.

Comment: I forgot to say that I must have to use an absolute positioning. Because it will have to overlap another div